# How do I rewrite the url in the browser but point to existing content

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Relatively new to URL redirect/rewriting in **IIS**.

I have a site `www.mysite.com/oldname`

I want to change the url in the browser to show:

`www.mysite.com/newname` but point at the content that is at `www.mysite.com/oldname`

And for every sub page:

`www.mysite.com/olname/*` -> `www.mysite.com/newname/*`

I created a redirect rule for oldsite to point to newsite - This works ok.

Then to get the content to display, I created a rewrite rule for the newsite url to appear in the browser but for oldsite content to display.  This works but only for the homepage.

As soon as I navigate to [www.mysite.com/oldpage/](http://www.mysite.com/oldpage/)* (ie: click on of the existing links) we just get the oldsite/* url in the browser again

Would appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use a redirect rule, but a full reverse proxy. See the ARR article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: Yes, reverse proxy is more suitable for you. It allows you show new site url in browser but the content is belong to old site.